# Intercept SOAP RPC method response without EJB

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws

I'm working on a project revamp for a company, where they want to split their system between front-end/client and back-end/server (more like a middleman between the front-end and the database server), and I'm supposed to use JAX-WS RPC and maintain the current functionality.

By maintaining functionality they mean that some methods are supposed to return null, which is forbidden by WS-I.

Searching for possible solutions, I stumbled upon this article: http://victor-ichim.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/rpcliteral-and-null-object-pattern.html which basically solves a similar problem by using EJB Interceptors to intercept and replace null results with empty objects.

Working around the concept, I thought of intercepting the results just like so, replacing null with something like a string template, intercepting it again on the client and replacing that template back with null.

My questions are:

1. They don't use EJB by default, so no Interceptors per se. Is there some implementation that could work for both Tomcat and JBoss?

   Even if I'm able to intercept the return server-side, how could I do it client-side?

   If I can use SOAPHandlers, how can I avoid raising the SOAP Fault for trying to return null?

Comment: Did you try using a handler https://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html/ ?

Comment: @VirtualTroll As mentioned, how could I avoid raising the fault? I've tried so, but the handler isn't invoked if the method returns null (not even handleFault), it just sends the notification straight to the client...

Comment: Can you provide the way the web-services are declared on both JBoss or Tomcat ? Last but not least, you might want to explore aspectJ (where you can target the termination of a method)

Comment: One more thing: are your webservices annoted with @SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT) or @SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC) ?

Comment: @VirtualTroll RPC, as required by them. Also, I did try switching to DOCUMENT, but that would also require non-overloading methods, which in turn would break current code that relies on the existing methods.
I think I'll prepare a basic sample of what I have currently and update my post as soon as possible.
The WS are declared via sun-jaxws.xml, poiting to the implementing class, which points via 'implements' to the SEI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I also had problems with JAXB not handling interfaces, what I ended up doing was using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation to enable (selectively, since every return and parameter that could practically be null needs to be annotated) converting values from and back to null, in sort of a hackjob manner. I created a generic-ish adapter for `Serializable` objects, and followed the same sort of approach for other kinds of `Object`s:

```
public class SerializableAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Serializable>>{
    
    private static final String NULL = "'NULL'"; // Will hopefully never collide
    
    @Override
    public Serializable unmarshal(String e) throws Exception {
        if (e == NULL) {
            return null;
        }
        byte [] eB = e.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
        InputStream iS = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(eB));
        ObjectInputStream oIS = new ObjectInputStream(iS);
        return (Serializable) oIS.readObject();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String marshal(Serializable o) throws Exception {
        if (o == null) {
            return NULL;
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream bAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oOS = new ObjectOutputStream(bAOS);
        oOS.writeObject(o);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bAOS.toByteArray());
    }
    
}
```

And then annotated every `Serializable` instance with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SerializableAdapter.class)` since using package-level `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters`didn't work for some reason, and so forth for other cases. JAXB seems to eagerly cast the types encoded to and from when calling the adapters, so it will compile just fine even if the object to be marshalled isn't an instance of the expected class/interface, and throw exceptions only at runtime.

**I don't recommend doing it this way, since it will require annotating every single method/parameter or package, and will break at the first one that didn't get annotated and yet received null.** This very adapter still serves a purpose for cases where I need to work with interfaces, and the implementing classes also implement Serializable, although there are cases that still need specific adapters, but that's usually badly thought-out code.

Partially because of the hackness of this and the hassle of annotating everything, I managed to convince the company to move away from SOAP RPC bindings, so I was able to have null parameters and returns without this.